# SVG images are not loaded on the page

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, svg

I have a website hosted on Amazon S3 (static website hosting). All other features are working but weirdly, SVG images are not loading.
Images are located in the sub directory of the site and path is correctly used.
Please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try browser inspect > network and check if svg images are correctly fetched?

Comment: Yes, they are fetched from s3 bucket.

Comment: Then please check the mime type, it needs to be `image/svg+xml`, otherwise there is problem on the hosting.

Comment: Currently, it is octet-stream ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to the S3 bucket where your website is hosted and select the svg file that you are having problem with. Go to Properties > Metadata, you will see its content-type is set to different value than `image/svg+xml` (octet-stream now)
Change it to `image/svg+xml` and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,my svg file missing value xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" in svg tag.